# Checkbox 'Checked' automatically when two other checkbox already 'checked'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have 3 checkboxes with different id, Checkbox1, checkbox2 and checkbox3.
how i can make checkbox 3 automatically checked if checkbox1 & checkbox2 is checked.

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="checkbox1">
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="checkbox2">
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="checkbox3">
```

**jquery**

```
var x = $("#checkbox1").is(':checked');
var y = $("#checkbox2").is(':checked');
if(x && y) {
document.getElementById("checkbox3").is(':checked');} 
else {document.getElementById("checkbox3").checked = false;
}
```

Comment: Bind `change` event on C1 & C2 and in handler check if both are checked, if yes then check C3 else uncheck C3.

Comment: can you give an example for bind checking 2 event C1 & C2 ? @Tushar

Comment: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/1d689rpn/)

Comment: lol, that is so simple. thankyou so much @Tushar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, check you code :D

`var y = $("#checkbox2").is('checked');`

should be:

`var y = $("#checkbox2").is(':checked');`

> **You can do:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.check').on('change',function() {
        var x = $("#checkbox1").is(':checked');
        var y = $("#checkbox2").is(':checked');
        $('#checkbox3').prop('checked',(x && y));
    });
});
</script>
```

hope this help ^^

Comment: lol, i'm sure i just write it wrong in that post but in my code it was right..
anyway, thankyou it works like a charm.. :)

just for note, answer from @Tushar is also correct.

Comment: For checkboxes I generally recommend using a `click` event rather than `change`, because in certain older browsers if you "click" the checkbox with the keyboard the `change` event isn't triggered until tabbing off it, whereas the `click` event is triggered immediately (even from the keyboard).

Comment: sure :) we can add more binding events e.g. .on('click change',function() { ... });

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe this will work, I am not 100% sure, but here:

```
var x = $("#checkbox1").is(':checked');
var y = $("#checkbox2").is('checked');
var z = $("#checkbox3").is('checked');
if(x && y && z) {
document.getElementById("checkbox3").is(':checked');} 
else {document.getElementById("checkbox3").checked = false;
}
```

Comment: *`document.getElementById("checkbox3").is(':checked')`* - That won't work. DOM elements don't have an `.is()` method, and in any case having that line in the `if` block wouldn't do anything.